# MySQL service not starting on XAMPP

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to start my XAMPP services. My Apache and ProFTPD are starting perfectly fine, however my MySQL service isn't starting. When I check the log, it says this:

```
ERROR: Failed to restart "mysql": cannot start service: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process
```

Then, after that, when I go to my browser, and go to my local server's PHPMyAdmin, it shows this there:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2LEm.png)

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: this link might help you https://medium.com/@kivaimuinde/resolve-opt-lampp-bin-mysql-server-264-kill-no-such-process-3a62d2331349

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work. To be specific, the mysql service couldn't stop because it wasn't even starting in the first place, and apparently the lampp command wasn't found. Was hoping someone could post an answer here which could help me instead...